# $S(f) = \underset{x \in X}{\sup } f(x)\ $ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I'd like to prove that the function $ S: \mathcal{B} (M;\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $S(f) = \underset{x \in  X}{\sup } f(x)\ $  is continuous.

$\mathcal{B}(M;\mathbb{R})$  is the set of all bounded functions from M into $\mathbb{R}$ and it is equipped with the metric 
$d(f,g) =\underset{x \in M}{\sup}|f(x)-g(x)|$.

I started with $d(S(f),S(g)) = | \underset{x \in  X}{\sup } f(x)\ -  \underset{x \in  X}{\sup } g(x)\ |$ and tried to find an upper bound related with $|f(x)-g(x)|$ but I didn't see a clear way to proceed.

I appreciate if you could give me some hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* For all $x \in X$,
 $$
 f(x) \le | f(x) - g(x) | + g(x) \le d(f,g) + S(g)
$$
which implies that
$$
S(f) \le d(f,g) + S(g) \, .
$$
Now exchange $f$ and $g$ and make a conclusion about
$|S(f) - S(g)|$.